# I need to check whether a property type is it's own class

Tags: c#, xamarin

Suppose I have this class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string PropertyOne;
    {
      get;set;
    }
    public MyClass Country;
    {
      get;set;
    }
}
```

I need to omit the properties having type of it's own class.
In my Code snippet, Country property should be omitted for my data model. How can I do that?

Comment: What is your definition of *own class*, do you mean not a value type, not a BCL .net class, your own class in your own library?

Comment: In this scenario I meant own class is a class in which that property has declared. Please refer Country property in my code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Data Annotations to exclude a property from the model.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public class MyClass
{
 public string PropertyOne { get; set; }
 [NotMapped]
 public MyClass Country { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In sample level this solution resolved my problem, but I want to exclude those kind of properties while generating labels.

Comment: I am going to generate Labels for all properties. If they were primitive types or complex class types no issues. But in case of above issue infinity loop occurs so my application crash. So I should able to remove those kind of properties.